# How can I use SMOTE in a Sklearn Pipeline for a NLP Classification problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline, smote

I'm dealing with a multiclass classification problem, in which some classes are very imbalanced. My data looks like this:

```
product_description                  class
"This should be used to clean..."    1
"Beauty product, natural..."         2
"Cleaning product, be careful..."    2
"Food, prepared with fruits..."      2
"T-shirt, sports, white, light..."   3
"Cleaning product, used to ..."      2
"Blue pants, two pockets, men..."    3
```

So I needed to make a classification model. This is what my pipeline currently looks like:

```
X = df['product_description']
y = df['class']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42
)

def text_process(mess):

    STOPWORDS = stopwords.words("english")

    # Check characters to see if they are in punctuation
    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

    # Join the characters again to form the string.
    nopunc = "".join(nopunc)

    # Now just remove any stopwords
    return " ".join([word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in STOPWORDS])

pipe = Pipeline(
steps=[
    ("vect", CountVectorizer(analyzer= text_process)),
    ("feature_selection", SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)),
    ("polynomial", PolynomialFeatures(2)),
    ("reg", LogisticRegression()),
]
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

However, I have a very imbalanced dataset, with the following distribution: class 1 - 80%, class 2 - 10%, class 3 - 5%, class 4 - 4%, class 5 - 1%. So I'm trying to apply SMOTE. However, I still couldn't understand where should SMOTE be applied.

At first, I thought about applying SMOTE before the Pipeline, but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '...'
```

So I thought about using SMOTE with the Pipeline. But I also got an error. I tried using SMOTE() in the first step and also in the second step, after CountVectorizer - this is what seemed logical to me -, but both returned the same error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'SMOTE()' (type <class 'imblearn.over_sampling._smote.base.SMOTE'>) doesn't
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue? What am I missing in here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a resampler like `SMOTE` requires the `imblearn` version of `Pipeline`.

This is because resamplers have to change both `X` and `y`, and ordinary `sklearn` pipelines do not do this.  The `imblearn` pipeline accommodates by allowing its intermediate steps to use either `transform` or `sample` (and importantly, resampling only happens during fitting, on the training data, and not on later transformations/predictions).  Otherwise it should operate the same as an ordinary `sklearn` pipeline.